# moved files into a new folder, now mod_rewrite isn't working?

Tags: apache

I'd got my head around mod rewrite, and got it working nice. So I then moved the site into a new folder, as we've now got two projects on the go on my dev server.

So I create a new folder, move all the files, and now mod rewrite isn't working ?

I moved the files from httpdocs to httpdocs/birds

Here's the mod rewrite stuff

```
RewriteEngine On    # Switch on rewriting
RewriteRule     ^birds/pages/([A-Za-z0-9\-]+).php?$ birds/index.php?page=$1                 [NC,L]  # Handle site navigation
```

I'm pretty sure this is something I'm doing wrong, I've tried several ways around... still no joy ?

Rich ;)

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the "/" for the target rewrite and you added an extra "?" after the php which won't match anything:

```
RewriteRule     ^birds/pages/([A-Za-z0-9\-]+)\.php$ /birds/index.php?page=$1                 [NC,L]
```

Comment: it's still doing the same thing... the url is populated into the address bar as /birds/pages/Services.php but the page doesn't load, if I manually type in /birds/index.php?page=Services it works

Answer (score 0):

You are also missing the "/" in the match:

```
RewriteRule     ^/birds/pages/([A-Za-z0-9\-]+)\.php$ /birds/index.php?page=$1
```